Concern About Transformer-like Noise in Monitor at Higher Refresh Rates
Is this transformer-like sound normal? The sound is similar to that of an incandescent lamp, and it can only be heard in the lower right corner of the screen. It gets louder when I increase the refresh rate to 100Hz and is almost inaudible at 60Hz. Should I return the product, or is this not considered a defect? I am hesitant because the IPS panel of this monitor is perfect and free of typical defects, which is quite fortunate.
In the video, after the "click," I turn on the monitor; before that, it is off.
Display: Dell S2425HS
Addition: In the place where the sound is coming from, there is one of the two built-in speakers. Could the speaker be producing this high-frequency sound due to the magnetic fields created during the matrix update (by the controller or something else, I'm not very knowledgeable about this)?

Normal? It depends, but probably not. Noises like this will usually indicate a low-quality component, or one that should have failed quality control, is in a state of overwork and could indicate failure sooner than expected. If the screen is new enough, I would pursue warranty service.

I decided to get a refound.

There might be minimal noises coming from new equipment, but only noticeable if you are trying to listen hard enough. Definitely sounds like either a defect in the monitor or the monitor that you have is already defective. Better get it replaced, see if the same issue happens with the replacement monitor or try a different model or brand of monitor entirely if you still have that option.
